# Jmeter remote server authentication

Tags: jmeter

When configuring a JMeter remote server, is there a way to enable authentication on the remote service like for example basic authentication ?

Basically I would like to protect my JMeter remote server with authentication. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's already [protected by SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) so you won't be able to establish RMI connection to the JMeter slave without having a [Keystore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) containing the certificates.

If this is not the case for you then make sure to have `server.rmi.ssl.disable` [JMeter property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) set to `false` in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation on master and all the slaves

Comment: but this is for encrypting traffic, I'm asking about authentication

Comment: the client can always disable ssl verification and still connect to a jmeter slave ssl encrypted endpoint